# How to delete an element from MatrixSpace(GF(2), 1, 2) in sage

Tags: sage

I need to delete one particular matrix from the matrix space in *sage*.
For example matrix space is `MS = MatrixSpace(GF(2), 1, 2)`. I want to delete `MS[0]` from MS in sage.

Comment: What do you mean, "delete"?  It wouldn't be a *space* any more if you did that, right?

Comment: Ya. I just want to do Cartesian product of subset of MS = MatrixSpace(GF(2), 1, 2) and MS\{MS[0]} for my research related to coding theory

Comment: I think that some coding stuff in Sage is there natively, you might want to look at that instead.

Comment: I didn't find anything related to Cartesian product (of codes) in sage. In sage only linear codes are more concentrated.